# Group a list of events into a dictionary of events by date

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I've been trying to learn RxJava2 and I've been struggling with this one..

So, I have a structure that represents an events that goes something like the following:

```
class Event{
    public Date when;
    public String eventName;
}
```

And somewhere I query a list of events from the repository that I want to group by date.

So, given a list of events like:

- Event1 at June
- Event2 at June
- Event3 at July
- Event4 at August
- Event5 at August

I want to group them so that

- June

  - Event1
  - Event2
- July

  - Event3
- August

  - Event4
  - Event5

What I have so far is, in my opinion, very ugly and I am pretty sure I am over-"engineering" this...

```
repository.getAllEvents()
            .toObservable()
            .flatMap(new Function<Events, Observable<Event>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Event> apply(@NonNull Events events) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(events.getEvents());
                }
            })
            .groupBy(new Function<Event, Date>() {
                @Override
                public Date apply(@NonNull Event event) throws Exception {
                    return event.when;
                }
            })
    .flatMap(new Function<GroupedObservable<Date, Event>, Observable<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Object> apply(@NonNull GroupedObservable<Date, Event> dateEventGroupedObservable) throws Exception {
            final Date key = dateEventGroupedObservable.getKey();
            return dateEventGroupedObservable.toList().toObservable().flatMap(new Function<List<Event>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(@NonNull List<Event> events) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.just(new Pair<Date, List<Event>>(key, events));
                }
            });
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeWith(new Observer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object o) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```

So far, this gives me an observable that delivers a Pair> but as you can see it gets converted to Object and I honestly can't make sense out of the generics hell -.-'

Any tips on how I could approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this simply by using `collect` operator:

```
repository.getAllEvents()
    .flatMapIterable(events -> events.getEvents())
    .collect(() -> new HashMap<Date, List<Event>>(), 
             (map, event) -> putEventIntoMap(map, event)
    )
    ...
```

Without lambdas:

```
// I assume that getAllEvents returns Events class
repository.getAllEvents()
    .flatMapIterable(new Function<Events, Iterable<? extends Event>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<? extends Event> apply(@NonNull Events events) throws Exception {
           return events.getEvents();
        }
    })
    .collect(new Callable<HashMap<Date, List<Event>>>() {
        @Override
        public HashMap<Date, List<Event>> call() throws Exception {
            return new HashMap<Date, List<Event>>();
        }}, new BiConsumer<HashMap<Date, List<Event>>, Event>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull HashMap<Date, List<Event>> map, @NonNull Event event) throws Exception {
            putEventIntoMap(map, event);
        }}
    )
    ...
```

Method to put event into map:

```
private void putEventIntoMap(HashMap<Date, List<Event>> map, Event event) {
    if (map.containsKey(event.when)) {
        map.get(event.when).add(event);
    } else {
        List<Event> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(event);
        map.put(event.when, list);
    }
}
```

Comment: @João I fixed some mistakes and added non-lamda code

Comment: thank you very very much for you answer, unfortunately the blockingGet() part makes the BiConsumer to suddendly stop and subsequent subscribers don't get executed.

Comment: I've found a simpler solution using only `collect`. I updated my answer. Btw why stream was blocked described here - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3611

Comment: Thanks for interesting question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Maxim Ostrovidov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42917695/5752112) I was able to adapt it into the following working solution:

```
repository.getAllEvents()
    // Convert the Single<Events> into an Observable<Events>
    .toObservable()

    // Transform the stream Events into a List<Event> stream / observable
    .flatMapIterable(new Function<Events, List<Event>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Event> apply(@NonNull Events events) throws Exception {
            return events.getEvents();
        }
    })

    // Group each Event from the List<Event> by when (date)
    .groupBy(new Function<Event, Date>() {
        @Override
        public Date apply(@NonNull Event event) throws Exception {
            return event.when;
        }
    })

    // For each grouped stream (not sure if its correct to call it like this)
    // Lets generate a new stream that is a Pair<Date, List<Event>>
    .flatMap(new Function<GroupedObservable<Date, Event>, Observable<Pair<Date, List<Event>>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Pair<Date, List<Event>>> apply(@NonNull GroupedObservable<Date, Event> dateEventGroupedObservable) throws Exception {
            final Date key = dateEventGroupedObservable.getKey();
            // toList() takes a big role here since it is forcing 
            // for the dateEventGroupedObservable to complete and only then 
            // streaming a Single<List<Event>> which is why I convert it back to observable
            return dateEventGroupedObservable.toList().toObservable().flatMap(new Function<List<Event>, Observable<Pair<Date, List<Event>>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Pair<Date, List<Event>>> apply(@NonNull List<Event> events) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.just(new Pair<Date, List<Event>>(key, events));
                }
            });
        }
    })

    // We can now collect all streamed pairs of (Date, List<Event>) 
    // into an HashMap
    .collect(new Callable<HashMap<Date, List<Event>>>() {
        @Override
        public HashMap<Date, List<Event>> call() throws Exception {
            return new HashMap<Date, List<Event>>();
        }
    }, new BiConsumer<HashMap<Date, List<Event>>, Pair<Date, List<Event>>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull HashMap<Date, List<Event>> dateListHashMap, @NonNull Pair<Date, List<Event>> dateListPair) throws Exception {
            dateListHashMap.put(dateListPair.first, new ArrayList<Event>(dateListPair.second));
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeWith(new SingleObserver<HashMap<Date, List<Event>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(HashMap<Date, List<Event>> dateListHashMap) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }
    });
```

Yes, it is long and it is ugly but I am pretty sure that with lambdas this would look better. Now, the thing is... This code is used to feed a recycler view adapter so I wonder if it wouldn't be easier to simple do this in an imperative way... oh well, serves the study purpose :)